# A resource to browse various function graphs?

Tags: reference-request, functions, graphing-functions, online-resources

I couldn't find what I need from google, so I figured it's time to ask here.

Basically I'm looking for something like an online catalogue for all kinds of function graphs. I need a few specific ones and it wouldn't hurt to look for other options in case I don't find what I'm looking for.

If someone's wondering, I need those for image manipulation algorithms.

Comment: Just functions, or curves in general?

Comment: Functions I think. Can you give me an example for a curve, just to see if I get the difference?

Comment: For curves in general, [this](http://2dcurves.com/) and [this](http://www.mathcurve.com/) (en français) are the online catalogs I usually consult. For books, there's [von Seggern](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=YTyHZwEACAAJ) and [Shikin](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=_bpdsNuyUegC).